# javascript : setInterval with global variables

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

**here in the example blow**

in my project i'm i facing the same problem and it is how to make the 
`setInterval` play with the click time `href` variable ?

i mean if i clicked the first anchor 5 times then i clicked the second anchor 3 times before the first `setInterval` end.

all the results in the `console log` will be 8 times of the second `href` value and this is normal i know... but what i need is 5 times for first anchor and 3 times for the second any idea?

***note***

for some reason `href` variable must be global variable

```js
var href = null;
$('a').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  href = $(this).attr('href');
  var timeLeft = 3000;
  var counterInterval = setInterval(function() {
    timeLeft -= 20;
    if (timeLeft < 0) {
      console.log(href);
      window.clearInterval(counterInterval);
    }
  }, 20);
})
```

```html
<a href="first">first anchor</a>
<a href="second">second anchor</a>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: What is your reasoning for saying href 'must' be global?  Every click of a different 'a' will overwrite it.  Also given your setup.  Each interval is going to execute... ~150 times.  Once you spawn a time interval it is, for all intensive purposes, asynchronous.  Trying to guarantee order of randomly started time intervals isn't really plausable.

Comment: Seems unclear to me!

Comment: the reason why i said it must be global is there an [plugin](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Dogfalo/materialize/master/js/toasts.js) i want to add one more argument called data 
and all i want is return my data synchronously `data` argument here is global so when i call the `toast` function twice or more than one in general data well equal to the last time value ?!
any tricks ?

Answer (score 1):

Change your code to this:

```
// You're right, href is a global variable which isn't necessary in the demonstration, you can simply remove it
// var href = null;

$('a').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    // let's declare a local variable, href is local to this event
    var href = $(this).attr('href');

    // change your block to a self invoking function
    // the key is that it accepts a parameter and we pass in the href
    (function(v) {
        var timeLeft = 3000;
        var counterInterval = setInterval(function() {
            timeLeft -= 20;
            if (timeLeft < 0) {
                // now we use the parameter v that was passed in
                console.log(v);
                window.clearInterval(counterInterval);
            }
        }, 20);
    })(href);  // <<<<<< this is where we pass in the local href to the self invoke function
});
```

Comment: thank u for u help i'am really appreciate it 
cloud you please look at my comment up in the main question my u get the idea of what i need to do 
thank you again

Comment: If you are saying that you need href to be global because it's being used somewhere else, then we need more info/context.  My answer was referring to why you get the output in the console.log when you clicked the a tags via the setIntervals.  Give us more info and we'll try to help.